# Insert text or overwrite region

Tags: region, insert

In an Emacs Lisp function, I would like to insert some text at point or - if the region is active - overwrite it with such text.  How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

For Emacs setting:

```
(delete-selection-mode t)  ; delete seleted text when typing
```

For lisp code, add following line before insert:

```
(if (region-active-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to do that from Lisp code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully.  I updated my answer, hope it helps.